# Hide git notes in TortoiseGit Log Message dialog

Tags: git, tortoisegit, gerrit, refspec

I'm working with Gerrit and TortoiseGit. When I show the log, it shows many commits with the comment

```
Update notes for submitted changes
```

They are not connected to my working commits. It looks like they come from the refs "**notes/review**". How can I hide them?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i was not really able to delete them but this helped me:

i deleted the file

```
.git\refs\notes\review
```

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the link(see the following figure), and click `All basic refs` item in context menu.
[image]

Then, the note refs do not show any more:

[image]

Comment: I could kiss you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ref for notes. It is normal to be there.

Comment: may be but it's verry annoying always to scroll 100 of the same notice commit, is there no possibility to hide them?